# on 'Click' upload individual files at table row instead of multiple upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have dynamic table table with 4 columns. The first 3 at each row has an input type='file' where a user can choose a file to upload and on the 4th column has a submit button in-line with the rows. Submitting files in the first row it will work fine but i am not able to do it for the rest of rows.

```js
$("#UpSubmit").on("click", function() {

  var rowSub = $(this).closest('tr');


  var file_data = rowSub.find('.file-input').prop("files")[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('file', file_data);

  var file_data1 = rowSub.find('.file-input1').prop("files")[0];
  var form_data1 = new FormData();
  form_data1.append('file', file_data1);

  var file_data2 = rowSub.find('.file-input2').prop("files")[0];
  var form_data2 = new FormData();
  form_data2.append('file', file_data2);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php', 

    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',

  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',

    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data1,
    type: 'post',

  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',  

    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data2,
    type: 'post',

  });

});
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? You don't see the other 2 requests in your network tab?

Comment: From the table The submit button does not work on 2nd or 3rd row to upload files  but on the 1st row i can select the 3 files on each column and hit the submit button @AnuragSrivastava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class `UpSubmit` to the button and use `$(".UpSubmit")`

`id`s in HTML are unique and you won't be able to have multiple buttons with the same `id`

Comment: I am calling the button <input type='submit' value='submit' class='btn btn-success' id='UpSubmit' name='UpSubmit' >  the button is echoed in each row

Comment: In the echo statement use `<input type='submit' value='submit' class='btn btn-success UpSubmit' name='UpSubmit' />`